# Idiom for things going wrong one after another

Tags: idiom-requests

I know I've heard of an idiom which means : Something was already wrong, and more bad thing(s) got added on top of it. I just cant remember it now.

Its not "striking someone when they're already down" - this has a connotation of someone actively trying to cause harm. What I'm looking for is more passive, like bad things just happen one after another.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/521176/idioms-for-saying-when-ones-bad-situation-compounded-with-more-problems/521329#521329

Answer (score 0):

### It never rains but it pours

> *chiefly British, informal*
> used to say that when something bad happens other bad things usually happen at the same time
>
> - The team not only lost the game but three of its best players were injured. **It never rains but it pours.**

Source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/it%20never%20rains%20but%20it%20pours)

You can also use "it doesn't just rain it pours", which I have heard and used.

Comment: It's interesting that the classic song "It never rains in Southern California" about an aspiring actor struggling in Hollywood contains the line "It never rains in California, but girls don't they warn ya, it pours, man it pours" which makes it sound as though it's an American idiom. However the songwriter, Albert Hammond, was born in London to Gibraltarian parents.